# Every map $\mathbb{RP}^4 \to S^3$ induces the zero map on $\pi_4(\mathbb{RP}^4)$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show that every map $f : \mathbb{RP}^4 \to S^3$ induces the zero map on $\pi_4(\mathbb{RP}^4)$. Here's what I've tried:

Using cellular approximation, we can assume that $f$ is cellular, so $f$ factors through $\mathbb{RP}^4/\mathbb{RP}^2 \simeq \Sigma^2 (\mathbb{RP}^2)$. I thought that somehow I could use the facts that $S^3 \simeq \Sigma^2(S^1)$ and that every map $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to S^1$ is null-homotopic. But then I got stuck.

Another approach that I've tried is to show that $f$ factors through $\mathbb{RP}^5$ (which is equivalent to what I'm trying to prove, if I'm not mistaken), but I got stuck again.

I would really appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$q:\mathbb{R}P^4\rightarrow S^4\cong \mathbb{R}P^4/\mathbb{R}P^3$$

be the map pinching to the top cell. Here are your hints: Show that $(1)$ every map $\mathbb{R}P^4\rightarrow S^3$ factors through $q$, $(2)$ $q$ induces the trivial map on *all* homotopy groups. Details follow.

$(1)$ Apply $[-,S^3]$ to the cofibration sequence

$$S^3\xrightarrow{\gamma}\mathbb{R}P^3\xrightarrow{i}\mathbb{R}P^4\xrightarrow{q}S^4\rightarrow\dots$$

where $\gamma$ is the 2-sheeted universal covering and $i$ is the subcomplex inclusion. You get

$$\pi_3S^3\xleftarrow{\gamma^*}[\mathbb{R}P^3,S^3]\xleftarrow{i^*}[\mathbb{R}P^4,S^3]\xleftarrow{q^*}\pi_4S^3\leftarrow\dots$$

Now $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is an orientable 3-manifold, so by the Hopf degree theorem $[\mathbb{R}P^3,S^3]\cong \mathbb{Z}$ as a group, and is generated by the map $p:\mathbb{R}P^3\rightarrow S^3$ which pinches to the top cell. By studying homology you know that $p_*:H_3\mathbb{R}P^3\rightarrow H_3S^3$ is an isomorphism, and that $\gamma_*:H_3S^3\rightarrow H_3\mathbb{R}P^3$ is multiplication by $2$. The conclusion from this is that the composite $p\gamma=\gamma^*(p):S^3\rightarrow S^3$ is the degree $2$ map. From this you see that the left-most map in the Puppe sequence above is the injection $\gamma^*=\times 2:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$. Thus you get exactness of

$$0\leftarrow[\mathbb{R}P^4,S^3]\xleftarrow{q^*}\pi_4S^3\leftarrow\dots$$

and conclude $(1)$.

$(2)$ Let $\rho:S^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^4$ be the universal cover. Recall that $\pi_1\mathbb{R}P^4\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, and $\rho_*:\pi_kS^4\rightarrow\pi_k\mathbb{R}P^4$ is an isomorphism for $k\geq 2$.

By studying homology you find that the map induced by the composite $S^4\xrightarrow{\rho} \mathbb{R}P^4\xrightarrow{q} S^4$ is the zero homomorphism. This is true because it passes through $H_4\mathbb{R}P^4=0$, which is trivial because $\mathbb{R}P^4$ is non-orientable. The conclusion is that $q\rho:S^4\rightarrow S^4$ is null-homotopic.

By the above remarks we know that $\pi_4\mathbb{R}P^4$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and is generated by $\rho$. Thus any element in $\pi_4\mathbb{R}P^4$ can be represented as a multiple $n\cdot[\rho]$ for some integer $n$. But this means that we have

$$q_*(n\cdot [\rho])=n\cdot (q_*[\rho])=n\cdot [q\circ\rho]=n\cdot[\ast]=0$$

and can conclude that $q_*:\pi_4\mathbb{R}P^4\rightarrow\pi_4 S^4$ is zero.

Note at this stage that we can conclude the stronger statement that $q_*$ is the zero homomorphism in *all* degrees.

$(3)$ Assemble: By (1) any map $f:\mathbb{R}P^4\rightarrow S^3$ can be factored up to homotopy as

$$f:\mathbb{R}P^4\xrightarrow{q} S^4\rightarrow S^3$$

where the second arrow may be inessential. It follows that $f_*:\pi_*\mathbb{R}P^4\rightarrow\pi_*S^3$ factors

$$f_*:\pi_*\mathbb{R}P^4\xrightarrow{q_*}\pi_*S^4\rightarrow\pi_*S^3$$

and we've seen in $(2)$ that the first homomorphism here is trivial.

Comment: So is it also the case that all maps in $[\mathbb{R}P^4,S^3]$ are null homotopic?

Comment: @ConnorMalin the exact sequence shows that the set $[\mathbb{R}P^4,S^3]$ is a quotient of $\pi_4S^3\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus we have at most two distinct homotopy classes. Namely the constant map and the composite $f:\mathbb{R}P^4\xrightarrow{q}S^4\xrightarrow{\eta}S^3$. I didn't check if $f$ is null-homotopic, but the first thing to try would be to extend the Puppe sequence to the right with $[\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^3,S^3]$. Then you can resolve this set using the cofbration sequence $S^3\rightarrow\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^2\rightarrow\Sigma\mathbb{R}P^3\rightarrow S^4$.